# Ubuntu Touch Terminal - hide keyboard and customize shortcut keys?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

For the Terminal app on Ubuntu Touch:

- There is a button to show keyboard, but it gets covered when the keyboard is shown. What is the proper way to hide the keyboard? So far, I've discovered that if you slide the app a bit so the list of background apps is shown, the keyboard gets autohidden, but this looks too hackish to me - there must be a better way?
- How can I press Ctrl-Shift-V to paste in Terminal? There is no Ctrl or Shift on the virtual keyboard, there are shortcuts defined for Ctrl-C though.. Can I edit these shorcuts somehow, so I can add Ctrl-Shift-V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long tap on the terminal to hide the keyboard.

No idea about the Ctrl-Shift-V though there is a selection mode if all you want is to paste. This works the same as other apps ie. tap and hold where you want to paste.

Comment: Thanks for that @ShaneQful - had no idea this is how it works, but it does :) Cheers!